# IQueryable is set to null when trying to OrderBy date property from class

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am new to link, this is my first task using it, and it is not going well. 
I have a page that can be sorted by the column the gets clicked on. 
One of the columns is a Date column, DateSubmitted.

I am getting an error of object not set to instance of object...

I stepped through the code and noticed that the list object contains values only until it passes the orderby line of code. I think that happens because the dateAccepted property contains null value, right before the assignemnt data = data.OrderBy..., data holds 416 records, after passes the assignment, then it has null, and throws the error.

I have another question similar to this one, I apologize for the duplication, but I truly need some explanation, if possible, and some help on how to work around this.

I tried to add HasValue after dateAccepted, but that does not make a difference.

Any help is valuable. Thank you very much.

```
    var data = (from c in starter
                select new ACPListObject()
                {
                    contact = c,
                    Year = Year,
                    LastSentDate = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.sentDateTime).FirstOrDefault(),
                    LastSubmit = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.ACPForm).FirstOrDefault(),
                    lastFormComplete = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s).FirstOrDefault(),
                    isMyContact = (from m in c.smsEmployeeContacts where m.empID == userID select m).Any()
                });

    if (isCurrentYear)
    {
        var custs = (from c in emptyCustomers.ToList()
                     where c.ISCTBillingActive || c.ISFFDMBillingActive || c.IsMRIBillingActive || (c.IsPETBillingActive && c.custType != 2)
                     select new ACPListObject()
                     {
                         contact = new smsCustomerContact() { cntID = -1, smsCustomer = c, cntActive = true },
                         Year = Year,
                         LastSentDate = new DateTime(),
                         LastSubmit = (ACPForm)null,
                         lastFormComplete = (smsContactFormSent)null,
                         isMyContact = false
                     });

        var combined = data.ToList();
        combined.AddRange(custs);
        data = combined.AsQueryable();                

    }
        else if (sortColumn == "DateSubmitted")
    {
        if (asc)
        {   
          data = data.OrderBy(o => o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm.dateAccepted);
        }
        else
        {
            data = data.OrderByDescending(o => o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm.dateAccepted);                    
        }
    }


    return data.ToList();           
}
```

EDIT 
I tried your proposed solution, I thought it was working but for some reason the values for dateAccepted aka "dateSubmitted" are not being populated.

They way that the objects are connected in the code to get the dateAccepted is like this:

ACPListObject

```
        public class ACPListObject
{
    public smsCustomerContact contact { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSentDate { get; set; }
    public ACPForm LastSubmit { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateAccepted { get; set; }
    public smsContactFormSent lastFormComplete { get; set; }
    public bool isMyContact { get; set; }
}
```

smsContactFormSent

```
    public partial class smsContactFormSent
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public int cntID { get; set; }
    public int sentBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime sentDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> acpID { get; set; }

    public virtual ACPForm ACPForm { get; set; }
    public virtual smsCustomerContact smsCustomerContact { get; set; }
    public virtual smsEmployee smsEmployee { get; set; }
}

public partial class ACPForm
{
    public ACPForm()
    {
        this.ACPFormContacts = new HashSet<ACPFormContact>();
        this.smsContactFormSents = new HashSet<smsContactFormSent>();
    }

    public int acpID { get; set; }
    public int romID { get; set; }
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dateSent { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dateAccepted { get; set; }

}
```

Could it be that I am not getting the values because I am not accessing smsContactFormSent correctly?

This is how I implemented your solution:

```
    public class ACPListObject
{
    public smsCustomerContact contact { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSentDate { get; set; }
    public ACPForm LastSubmit { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateAccepted { get; set; }
    public smsContactFormSent lastFormComplete { get; set; }
    public bool isMyContact { get; set; }
}

            var data = (from c in starter
                    select new ACPListObject()
                    {
                        contact = c,
                        Year = Year,
                        LastSentDate = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.sentDateTime).FirstOrDefault(),
                        LastSubmit = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.ACPForm).FirstOrDefault(),
                        lastFormComplete = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s).FirstOrDefault(),
                        dateAccepted = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.ACPForm.dateAccepted).FirstOrDefault(), //note that I am selecting dateAccept here so, this will be a DateTime or null                          
                        isMyContact = (from m in c.smsEmployeeContacts where m.empID == userID select m).Any()
                    });

            else if (sortColumn == "DateSubmitted")
        {
            if (asc)
            {   
              //data = data.OrderBy(o => o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm.dateAccepted);                  
              data = data.OrderBy(o => o.dateAccepted);//order by new variable
            }
            else
            {
                //data = data.OrderByDescending(o => o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm.dateAccepted);                    
                data = data.OrderByDescending(o => o.dateAccepted); //order by new variable
            }
        }
```

When a new ContactForm gets sent, the value for dateSubmitted is not populated. I keep diggin and see if the error is from somewhere else. Thank you so much for your help Marcos.

Comment: Probably o.lastFormComplete is null or  o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm is null. If dateAccepted is null won't throw any exception.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Marcos. Do you have a suggestion as to what I can try to remedy the exception? Many thanks.

Comment: You could get only the records that o.lastFormComplete are not null and o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm are not null, but I don't know if you want this: `data = data.Where(o => o.lastFormComplete != null && o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm != null).OrderBy(o => o.lastFormComplete.ACPForm.dateAccepted);`

Comment: I think I still need to be a able to display the records on the page, the functionality is intended to only sort by column, not to filter the records to be displayed :/

Comment: Then include de dateAccepted in the class ACPListObject and select the value if c.smsContactFormSents.Count() > 0 to the dateAccepted or null in other case,  then you could order by this variable even if is null. I will try to write you an example in answer

Comment: This question has turned into a mess. Is there still a problem, and if yes, what's the problem?

Comment: This solution is complete. Thanks for all the kind help Marcos Gonzales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution and adapt to your model.

```
 var data = (from c in starter
                    select new ACPListObject()
                    {
                        contact = c,
                        Year = Year,
                        LastSentDate = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.sentDateTime).FirstOrDefault(),
                        LastSubmit = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.ACPForm).FirstOrDefault(),
                        lastFormComplete = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s).FirstOrDefault(),
                        dateAccepted  = (from s in c.smsContactFormSents orderby s.sentDateTime descending select s.ACPForm.dateAccepted).FirstOrDefault(), //note that I am selecting dateAccept here so, this will be a DateTime or null
                        isMyContact = (from m in c.smsEmployeeContacts where m.empID == userID select m).Any()
                    });

        if (isCurrentYear)
        {
            var custs = (from c in emptyCustomers.ToList()
                         where c.ISCTBillingActive || c.ISFFDMBillingActive || c.IsMRIBillingActive || (c.IsPETBillingActive && c.custType != 2)
                         select new ACPListObject()
                         {
                             contact = new smsCustomerContact() { cntID = -1, smsCustomer = c, cntActive = true },
                             Year = Year,
                             LastSentDate = new DateTime(),
                             LastSubmit = (ACPForm)null,
                             lastFormComplete = (smsContactFormSent)null,
                             isMyContact = false
                         });

            var combined = data.ToList();
            combined.AddRange(custs);
            data = combined.AsQueryable();                

        }
        else if (sortColumn == "DateSubmitted")
        {
            if (asc)
            {   
                data = data.OrderBy(o => o.dateAccepted);//order by new variable
            }
            else
            {
                data = data.OrderByDescending(o => o.dateAccepted); //order by new variable
            }
        }


        return data.ToList();
```

EDIT:
You should add the dateAccepted to ACPListObject class if it is possible:

```
public class ACPListObject
{
    public smsCustomerContact contact { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSentDate { get; set; }
    public ACPForm LastSubmit { get; set; }
    public smsContactFormSent lastFormComplete { get; set; }
    public bool isMyContact { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

If you can't add this property then this solution is not valid. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hola Marcos. Thank you for your help with the code. I am not at the computer where I can try it and see if it works. As soon as I am able to give it a try, I will make a post. Thanks

Comment: Hi again. I added a comment earlier today with code and about an issue I am having with the proposed solution. Did you deleted that code? I cannot see it anymore. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't delete, put the update in your own post to be more clear.

Comment: This solution is complete. Thank you Marcos Gonzales for your kind help.